# Returning a string * type array from a function back into the main

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers

I'm new to C++ and I am working on a function to shuffle strings

It takes an array of strings, shuffles them, and returns them back to the main.

I am returning a pointer to an array of strings called `shuffled`. The problem I have is that when I try to save that new pointer to the array to another pointer in the main, I start getting weird values that either reference to a file location in my computer or a bunch of numbers.

I'll post the entire code here but really what you want to look at is the return types, how I return it and how I save it in main. Please tell me why my pointer is not referencing the working array that is created in the function. Here's the code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <new>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

const char * getString(const char * theStrings[], unsigned int stringNum)
{
    return theStrings[stringNum];
}

string * shuffleStrings(string theStrings[])
{
    int sz = 0;
    while(!theStrings[sz].empty())
    {
        sz++;
    }
    sz--;
    int randList[sz];
    for(int p = 0; p < sz; p++)
    {
        randList[p] = sz;
    }

    srand(time(0));//seed randomizer to current time in seconds
    bool ordered = true;
    while(ordered)
    {
        int countNumberInRandList = 0;//avoid having a sz-1 member list length     (weird error I was getting)
        for(int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
        {
            int count = 0;
            int randNum = rand()%(sz+1);//get random mod-based on size
            for(int u = 0; u < sz; u++)
            {
                if(randList[u] != randNum)
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if(count == sz)
            {
                randList[i] = randNum;
                countNumberInRandList++;
            }
            else
                i--;
        }
        //check to see if order is same
        int count2 = 0;
        for(int p = 0; p < sz; p++)
        {
            if(randList[p] == p)
            {
                count2++;
            }
        }
        if(count2 < sz-(sz/2) && countNumberInRandList == sz)
        {
            ordered = false;
        }
    }
    string * shuffled[sz];
    for(int r = 0; r < sz; r++) //getting random num, and str list pointer from passed in stringlist and setting that value at shuffled [ random ].
    {
        int randVal = randList[r];
        string * strListPointer = &theStrings[r];
        shuffled[randVal] = strListPointer;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
    {
        printf("element %d is %s\n", i, shuffled[i]->c_str());//correct values in a random order.
    }
    return *shuffled;
}

int main()
{
    string theSt[] = {"a", "b", "pocahontas","cashee","rawr", "okc", "mexican", "alfredo"};
    string * shuff = shuffleStrings(theSt);//if looped, you will get wrong   values
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: getString as written is wrong, unused and pretty badly incompatible with the rest of your code...
as a file, try to simplify this down to the minimum of what is needed to reproduce your problem as opposed to just asking us to 'find your bug'.

also if you are trying to learn c++; consider use `cout` instead of `printf` and ditcth `cstdio`... might as well use features of the language you are using

Comment: Before you define your return types you need to clearly define your requirements and interface.  Are you trying to shuffle the array the user passes IN or are you trying to copy it into a new array which will be suffeled?

Comment: @ChristianHackl as a beginner I think you need assume here that part of the purpose of the exercise is actually learning how to deal with arrays, pointers, pointers to arrays, etc.... that said I still agree with you on the TL;DR part!
Bigger problem is horrendous mixture of c++ and c.  the only thing c++ about this is std::string and not initializing all variables at beginning of all functions.

Answer (score 1):

Strings allocate their own memory, no need to give them the "length" like you would have to do for char arrays. There are several issues with your code - without going into the details, here are a few working/non-working examples that will hopefully help you:

```
using std::string;

// Returns a string by value
string s1() {
  return "hello";  // This implicitly creates a std::string
}

// Also returns a string by value
string s2() {
  string s = "how are you";
  return s;
}

// Returns a pointer to a string - the caller is responsible for deleting
string* s3() {
  string* s = new string;
  *s = "this is a string";
  return s;
}

// Does not work - do not use!
string* this_does_not_work() {
  string s = "i am another string";
  // Here we are returning a pointer to a locally allocated string.
  // The string will be destroyed when this function returns, and the
  // pointer will point at some random memory, not a string! 
  // Do not do this!
  return &s;
}

int main() {
  string v1 = s1();
  // ...do things with v1...
  string v2 = s2();
  // ...do things with v2...
  string* v3 = s3();
  // ...do things with v3...
  // We now own v3 and have to deallocate it!
  delete v3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of things wrong here -- don't panic, this is what happens to most people when they are first wrapping their brains around pointers and arrays in C and C++. But it means it's hard to put a finger on a single error and say "this is it". So I'll point out a few things.

(But *advance warning*: You ask about the pointer being returned to `main`, your code does indeed do something wrong with that, and I am about to say a bunch of things about what's wrong and how to do better. But *that is not actually responsible for the errors you're seeing*.)

So, in `shuffleStrings` you're making an array of pointers-to-string (`string * shuffled[]`). You're asking `shuffleStrings` to return a single pointer-to-string (`string *`). Can you see that these don't match?

In C and C++, you can't actually pass arrays around and return them from functions. The behaviour you get when you try tends to be confusing to newcomers. You'll need to understand it at some point, but for now I'll just say: *you shouldn't actually be making `shuffleStrings` try to return an array*.

There are two better approaches. The first is to use not an array but a *vector*, a container type that exists in C++ but not in C. You can pass arrays around by value, and they will get copied as required. If you made `shuffleStrings` return a `vector<string*>` (and made the other necessary changes in `shuffleStrings` and `main` to use vectors instead of arrays), that could work.

```
vector<string *> shuffleStrings(...) {
  // ... (set things up) ...
  vector<string *> shuffled(sz);
  // ... (fill shuffled appropriately) ...
  return shuffled;
}
```

But that is liable to be inefficient, because your program is then having to copy a load of stuff around. (It mightn't be so bad in this case, because a smallish array of pointers isn't very large and because C++ compilers are sometimes able to figure out what you're doing in cases like this and avoid the copying; the details aren't important right now.)

The other approach is to make the array not in `shuffleStrings` but in `main`; to pass a pointer to that array (or to its first element, which turns out to be kinda equivalent) into `shuffleStrings`; and to make `shuffleStrings` then modify the contents of the array.

```
void shuffleStrings(string * shuffled[], ...) {
  // ... (set things up) ...
  // ... (fill shuffled appropriately) ...
}

int main(...) {
  // ...
  string * shuffled[sz];
  shuffleStrings(shuffled, theSt);
  // output strings (main is probably a neater place for this
  // than shuffleStrings)
}
```

Having said all this, the problems that are causing your symptoms lie elsewhere, inside `shuffleStrings` -- after all, `main` in your code never actually uses the pointer it gets back from `shuffleStrings`.

So what's actually wrong? I haven't figured out exactly what your shuffling code is trying to do, but that is where I bet the problem lies. You are making this array of pointers-to-string, and then you are filling in *some* of its elements -- the ones corresponding to numbers in `randList`. But if the numbers in `randList` don't cover the full range of valid indices in `shuffled`, you will leave some of those pointers uninitialized, and they might point absolutely anywhere, and then asking for their `c_str`s could give you all kinds of nonsense. I expect that's where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing to do with any of the stuff you are saying.  As you are a beginner I would suggest not presuming that your code is correct.  Instead I would suggest removing parts that are not believed to be problematic until you have nothing left but the problem.

If you do this, you should quickly discover that you are writing to invalid memory.

part two : you can't seem to decide on the type of what you are returning.  Are you building a pointer to an array to return or are you returning an array of pointers.... you seem to switch between these intermittently.

part three : read @Gareth's answer, he explains about passing parameters around nicely for your instance.